# Is it possible to access a deployed Protected Google Web App via URL without logging in from browser each time?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, oauth, service-accounts, google-workspace

I've deployed a protected web app, and I'd like to trigger it without logging in each time: [image]

I'd like to access the web app URL without logging in:
[image]

Based on this document, it's not possible without logging in from browser:
https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script/blob/master/README.md

> If the script of Web Apps uses some scopes, client users have to
>   authorize the scopes by own browser.

I'm assuming `scopes` means the web app is protected.

I've tried this: https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/GoogleServiceAccount.gs but it asks for "request access"

[image: https://i.imgur.com/eRUaXlh.png]

If I click on `request access`, then it shows me this:
[image]

At this point, I'm thinking it's not possible to setup a service account with scope to trigger a protected deployed web app without authenticating through a browser each time. Can anyone confirm this?

My assumption is that the web app scope is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` since it has access to all drive's files.

**Update: (What I tried but didn't work)**

I matched the scope from the script:

[image]

To the service account:

[image]

The blurred area above is the client id i got from:

[image]

I've generated the access token using this script:

```
function accessTokens(){
 var private_key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----*****\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"; // private_key of JSON file retrieved by creating Service Account
var client_email = "****@****.iam.gserviceaccount.com"; // client_email of JSON file retrieved by creating Service Account
var scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"]; // Scopes


var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token";
var header = {
  alg: "RS256",
  typ: "JWT",
};
var now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
var claim = {
  iss: client_email,
  scope: scopes.join(" "),
  aud: url,
  exp: (now + 3600).toString(),
  iat: now.toString(),
};
var signature = Utilities.base64Encode(JSON.stringify(header)) + "." + Utilities.base64Encode(JSON.stringify(claim));
var jwt = signature + "." + Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature(signature, private_key));

var params = {
  method: "post",
  payload: {
    assertion: jwt,
    grant_type: "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
  },
};
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getContentText();
Logger.log(res); 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.getRange(1, 3).setValue(JSON.parse(res)['access_token']);
}
```

And still has the same error, it asks for request access.

Comment: When you created your service account, did you provide [domain wide authority delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority)?

Comment: I did yesterday, still no luck: https://i.imgur.com/nVqGgjV.png

Comment: I think this is particularly tricky because I have a gsuite business account.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, why do you need to access it via the Web-App URL if you don't want to use a browser, is there a reason you can't use a regular Apps Script Trigger to trigger the relevant code without accessing the web interface?

Comment: @TheMaster This was done yesterday as well: https://i.imgur.com/AfVaseW.png

@CameronRoberts I think you mean timed triggers? or onEdit/onOpen? I have hundreds of spreadsheets that I'd like to update on demand via `curl` rather than by events or timed since there's a limit in compute per account.

I may just have to allow anyone even anonymous to trigger it seems like.

Comment: @TheMaster figured it out! needed to adjust the script a bit and missed a few things. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Great. `have hundreds of spreadsheets` Why not just use the sheets api?

Comment: @TheMaster I didn't want to be limited by api limits https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/limits. To be honest, I will have thousands of spreadsheets. With api limits, I don't think I will have enough credits to operate efficiently since there could be hundreds or even a thousand spreadsheet updates per day. Also, I didn't want to write an app to handle the api just to trigger updates when I can use this method to trigger directly from postgresql.

Comment: FWIW, Web-apps are not without [limits](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) either.

Comment: Thanks, trying to work around this limits as much as possible. Will probably need multiple paid accounts in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple days into this, I've figured it out (with help of course).

1. Get the scope from your deployed web app script: `File > Project Properties > Scopes`
2. Add the scope along with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` in page `Manage API client access` https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?chromeless=1#OGX:ManageOauthClients (use comma delimited to add multiple scopes: `http...,http..., etc.`)
3. For the client name, get the client id from the service account page in your admin console: https://console.developers.google.com
4. Deploy your script `Publish > Deploy as Web App`
5. After generating access token(instruction below), append the access token with your deployed web app url `&access_token=YOURTOKENHERE`

Use this script with a google sheet, it will generate the access_token in cell `A1` of `Sheet1` (Replace the 4 variables with the info relevant to you):

```
function accessTokens(){
 var private_key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"; // private_key of JSON file retrieved by creating Service Account
var client_email = "*****@****.iam.gserviceaccount.com"; // client_email of JSON file retrieved by creating Service Account
var scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]; // Scopes
var impersonate_email = "" //impersonate email

var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
var header = {
  alg: "RS256",
  typ: "JWT",
};
var now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
var claim = {
  iss: client_email,
  sub: impersonate_email,
  scope: scopes.join(" "),
  aud: url,
  exp: (now + 3600).toString(),
  iat: now.toString(),
};
var signature = Utilities.base64Encode(JSON.stringify(header)) + "." + Utilities.base64Encode(JSON.stringify(claim));
var jwt = signature + "." + Utilities.base64Encode(Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature(signature, private_key));

var params = {
  method: "post",
  payload: {
    assertion: jwt,
    grant_type: "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
  },
};
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getContentText();
Logger.log(res); 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue(JSON.parse(res)['access_token']);
}
```